# Searching a access database for a part of a word

Tags: c#, linq

I have an access database that contains columns such as Title, Director, And Year.

I have access database connected to the program. I am able to search the database and print out the title of the movie to a listBox only if the title contains the one word. For example, if I search for the movie "psycho" the movie will display in the listBox.

Now I'm wondering how I can search for a particular word like "the" and print all the movie titles with "the" in it to the listBox.

At that point, the text book I'm using fails to go into anything deeper.
Maybe I'm not using the right method for what I'm trying to do.

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string lowerCaseData = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
        if (titleButton.Checked)
        {
            var query =
                from m in this.moviesDataSet.Movies
                where m.Title == lowerCaseData
                select m;
            foreach (var m in query)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(m.Title);
            }

        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'moviesDataSet.Movies' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.moviesTableAdapter.Fill(this.moviesDataSet.Movies);

    }
```

Comment: `where m.Title.Contains(lowerCaseData)` be aware, it is a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exact match check for `Contains`

---

Depending on the LINQ provider, `Contains` check should be translated to SQL `LIKE` statement which will be case insensitive, so your check should be:

```
where m.Title.Contains(lowerCaseData)
```

---

However for in-memory collections, `Contains` would perform a case sensitive match. In that case `String.IndexOf` can be used like:

```
where m.Title.IndexOf(lowerCaseData, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` query is doing an exact match.  Use `Contains` instead

```
where m.Title.ToLower().Contains(lowerCaseData)
```